# Exclude getters and setters from method count in CheckStyle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I got custom `checkstyle.xml` file with entry for MethodCount like this:

```
<module name="MethodCount">
    <property name="maxTotal" value="20"/>
    <property name="maxPrivate" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxPublic" value="10"/>
    <property name="severity" value="error"/>
</module>
```

However this creates a problem for huge model classes with getters and setters, which are provided by another web service. Can i somehow exclude this methods? Or is this considered a bad practice to not count those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `suppression.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionFilter Configuration 1.2//EN"
    "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_2.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress files="\w*(Dto.java|Entity.java)\b" checks="MethodCount"/>
</suppressions>
```

And point it in `checkstyle.xml`

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="./suppression.xml"/>
</module>
```

Then you will suppress check `MethodCount` for files ending with `Entity.java` or `Dto.java`

AFAIK you cannot suppress only getters/setters. Generally, for data structures like entities or dtos it is not a problem for having more than 5 fields with getters and setters.

But if you have real objects adding setter/getters for each field is considering a bad practice.

Comment: This is workaround, however after looking for this in documentation myself I can confirm that you can't exclude methods by name. You need to exclude the whole DTO classes.

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure if it's what you need but you can ignore getter and setter methods from inspections:

Goto `Settings` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), 
then Editor->Inspections->Java->Class metrics->Class with too many methods

[image]

Comment: Sadly changing this in Inspections tab does not make CheckStyle to change it's behaviour.